# Unable to mock the Datasource bean in spring boot test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

The sample test mocks `javax.sql.Datasource` using `@MockBean` annotation is not working, getting `Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean` error in spring boot version `2.3.0.RELEASE` or later.

This is the following code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {pService.class})
@Import({
    JdbcConfiguration.class
})
class DataMockTestApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class JdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
  @Value("${f.jdbc.url}")
  private String fUrl;

  @Value("${f.jdbc.username}")
  private String fUsername;

  @Value("${f.jdbc.password}")
  private String fPassword;

  @Bean
  NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

  @Bean(name = "fOperations")
  NamedParameterJdbcOperations fOperations() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl(fUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(fUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(fPassword);
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
}
```

```
@Component
@Qualifier("pService")
public class pService {
}
```

But in previous versions, it is working fine. Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE'    // ------> 1
    //id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.13.RELEASE'     //  ------> 2
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

If I uncomment line 2, tests were able to run and `2.3.0.RELEASE` version is immediate next version to `2.2.13.RELEASE`. Here is the code repo link https://github.com/maradanasai/data-mock-test

Comment: What did you expect? You have mocked Datasource bean and now it returns null in any method (as you haven't configured any method with mockito). Which is clearly stated in error message. I would also say that mocking Datasource is a questionable approach unless you really know what you do.

Comment: @ILyaCyclone Expectation is it should work with later version mentioned but it is not. Here null is not creating the issue, even with `2.2.13.RELEASE` version, datasource is null but it didn't failed